# How can I paint orange the firsts articles of each .fila class?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have this schematic:

```
<div class="fila">
    <div class="dos_tercios">
        <article>
            ......
        </article>
    </div>
    <div class="un_tercios">
        <article>
            ......
        </article>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="fila">
    <div class="un_tercios">
        <article>
            ......
        </article>
    </div>
    <div class="dos_tercios">
        <article>
            ......
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

And i want to paint with Orange the first article of each .fila class, or saying in other words, the left side articles (this is because after this i have to add diferent margint to right-hand articles and left-hand articles) (Watch image)

I have been trying this:

```
article:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: rgb(255, 177, 113);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this,

```css
.fila div:nth-child(1) article:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: rgb(255, 177, 113);
}
```

```html
<div class="fila">
      <div class="dos_tercios">
        <article>
          ......
        </article>
      </div>
      <div class="un_tercios">
        <article>
          ......
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="fila">
      <div class="un_tercios">
        <article>
          1st ......
        </article>
         <article>
          2nd ......
        </article>
      </div>
      <div class="dos_tercios">
        <article>
          ......
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Moreover to target the `odd` and `even` children you can use something like this

`article:nth-child(odd)` , `article:nth-child(even)`

as you were trying to do the same in the question.

Comment: And if i want to do with the second article of each .fila?

Comment: In place of `1` write `2`  ->  `.fila div:nth-child(2)`

Comment: If you want the same for `odd` or `even` children then in place of  `1` you can use `odd` or `even`.

Comment: you're selecting the div not article .. in case there are many articles in each div, it won't work

Comment: Yes, I didn't think of that, I just considered the existing query.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with below code:

```
.fila > div:nth-child(1) > article {
    background-color: rgb(255, 177, 113);
}
```

Due to `article` is not the directly child of `.fila` elements,so we need to get the first child by `.fila > div:nth-child(1)` then invoke `> article` to get the expected article element

```css
.fila > div:nth-child(1) > article {
    background-color: rgb(255, 177, 113);
}
```

```html
<div class="fila">
    <div class="dos_tercios">
        <article>
            A1......
        </article>
    </div>
    <div class="un_tercios">
        <article>
           A2 ......
        </article>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="fila">
    <div class="un_tercios">
        <article>
            B1......
        </article>
    </div>
    <div class="dos_tercios">
        <article>
           B2 ......
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.fila div:first-child article:first-child {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="fila">
  <div class="dos_tercios">
    <article>
      First Article
    </article>
    <article>
      ......
    </article>
    <article>
      ......
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="un_tercios">
    <article>
      First Article in Second div
    </article>
    <article>
      ......
    </article>
    <article>
      ......
    </article>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="fila">
  <div class="un_tercios">
    <article>
      First Article
    </article>
    <article>
      ......
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="dos_tercios">
    <article>
      First Article in Second div
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```